# TypeError: Highcharts.mapChart is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to plot a highmap in react using typescript. I have additionally loaded the highcharts types which include highmaps.

```
class InvestmentChart extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Highcharts.mapChart("investment", {
      chart: {
...
```

Cheers

See live [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nkrww6ly3l).

Comment: Always post relevant code in the question itself. You can still use code snippet here in SO.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [readme](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts#typescript), it looks like you need to do:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps';
```

instead of:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

I tried this [in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o9nokjr6vz) and it seemed to get past the point where you were stuck.

### Update

DefinitelyTyped appears to have some typings for Highmaps, though they are out of date.  The following method of importing Highmaps seems to get as far as the previous method at runtime in CodeSandbox and will use the typings:

```
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import MapFactory = require("highcharts/modules/map");
(MapFactory as any)(Highcharts);
```

[New CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8zj5w3xrv0).  Locally, I am still getting a type error because of the out-of-date declarations (`subtitle` is not recognized), but you can `//@ts-ignore` it.  I don't know why this error isn't appearing on CodeSandbox.

Comment: Well ok, but there is no such module. That is the result when trying in CodeSandbox

Comment: See the CodeSandbox I linked where it's working for me.

Comment: No, but I see the title "Highmaps basic demo" that demonstrates that the `Highcharts.mapChart` call is doing something.  Maybe you are not specifying the map correctly, but that's a different issue.

Comment: On my local environment, I still do not get it past that point. The issue is: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'highcharts/highmaps'. 'D:/Programming/Bitbucket/report-example/node_modules/highcharts/highmaps.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.` Is this related to the same issue as in CodeSandbox that there is no such modul?

Comment: `@types/highcharts` does not know of the module `highcharts/highmaps`.  See the updated answer for a method of getting the (out-of-date) type information available.

Comment: Now, it gives me the other errors locally which also appear in codesandbox. What seems to work locally is just using `import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highmaps';` and setting "noImplicitAny": false in tsconfig.json.